# Why my Contact Form 7 form is not working

Tags: wordpress, forms, contact-form-7

I am running the latest version of contact form 7 on my site and all of the forms are working flawlessly except one. I keep getting the message "Failed to send your message.

Please try later or contact the administrator by another method." I haven't come across any errors in the console and have tried everything from deleting the entire plugin and re-entering all the forms to deleting and recreating the problem form. I have tried all the troubleshooting suggestions I could find.

I am at a complete loss if anyone has any suggestions it would be incredibly helpful.

The form is located at: http://test.drummerrealty.com/management-services/#inquiries.
**Here is the code:**
Form:

#### Contact Information

```
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">

    <p>First Name *<br />
        [text* first-name] </p>

    <p>Last Name *<br />
    [text* last-name] </p>

</div>

<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
    <p>Your Email *<br />
        [email* your-email] </p>

    <p>Telephone *<br />
        [tel* tel-819]</p>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
    <p>Property Address<br />
        [text address]</p>

    <p>City<br />
       [text city]</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
    <p>Province<br />
       [text province]</p>

    <p>Postal Code<br />
       [text postal-code]</p>
</div>
```

```
<h3>Property Information</h3>

<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">

    <p>Property Class:<br />
       [select property use_label_element "Condominium" "Townhome" "Single Family Dwelling" "Apartment Block"]</p>

    <p>Year Built<br />
   [number build-year min:1900 max:3500]</p>

    <p>Number of Bedrooms:<br />
   [select num-bed "1" "2" "3" "4" "5+"]</p>

    <p>Number of Bathrooms:<br />
   [select num-bath "1" "1.5" "2" "2.5" "3" "3.5" "4" "4.5" "5+"]</p>

    <p>When do you plan to lease this property? (yyyy-mm-dd)<br />
    [date date-lease] </p>

</div>   

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">

    <p>Style &amp; Features<br />
       [checkbox features use_label_element "Bungalow" "2-storey" "Apartment" "Walk-out Basement" "Gated Community" "Parking " "Attached Garage" "Detached Garage"]</p>

<p>Square Footage<br />
   [number sq-foot]</p>

</div>
```

```
<div class="row">

<div class="col-sm-12">
    <p>Additional Details<br />
        [textarea add-details] </p>

    <p>[submit "Send"]</p>

</div>
```

Mail:

```
From: [first-name] [last-name]
Subject: Property Management form from [first-name] [last-name]

Message body:

Contact Information
First Name: [first-name]
Last Name: [last-name]
Your Email: [your-email]
Telephone: [tel-819]
Property Address: [address]
City: [city]
Province: [province]
Postal Code: [postal-code]

Property Information
Property Class: [property]
Style & Features: [features]
Square Footage: [sq-foot]
Year Built: [build-year]
Number of Bedrooms: [num-bed]
Number of Bathrooms: [num-bath]
When do you plan to lease this property?: [date-lease]
Additional Details: [add-details]
```

Comment: Look in your logs, not your console.